# Hartshorne II Prop. 6.8 (last step).

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am having trouble understanding the last line in the proof of this proposition. I have seen this question once on Math.SE and another time in MO, but I couldn't find in either case a clear solution to my doubt. Here is the situation and the claim that Hartshorne does:

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism between $X$ a complete nonsingular curve and $Y$ any curve such that $f(X)=Y$. We know then that $Y$ is also complete (but may be singular) and that $f$ induces a finite field extension $K(Y)\subseteq K(X)$ between the fraction fields. **Goal:** $f$ is a finite morphism, i.e. the preimage of an affine open $\operatorname{Spec}{B}$ is an affine open $\operatorname{Spec}{A}$ such that the induced ring morphism makes $A$ a finite $B$-module.

So let $V=\operatorname{Spec}{B}$ be an affine open of $Y$ (potentially with some singularities). Regard $B$ as a subring of $K(X)$ (via the identification with $f$) and let $A$ be the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$. Then $A$ is a Dedekind domain, finite $B$-module, with fraction field $K(X)$. $U=\operatorname{Spec}{A}$ is a nonsingular curve with fraction field $K(X)$, hence canonically an open subscheme of $X$ (because complete nonsingular curves are canonically isomorphic to the abstract complete nonsingular curve, whose closed points are the dvr's in the corresponding field). Hartshorne claims then that *clearly* $f^{-1}(V)=U$, but I fail to see why, let alone why this is at all so clear.

**My attempt:** the valuation rings of a field containing a Dedekind domain are precisely the localization of this Dedekind domain at the different non-zero prime ideals. Hence a closed point $P\in X$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $A$ if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\supseteq A$, and since $A$ is the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$, this is the case if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\supseteq B$. But this means precisely that the prime $P$ lies over some prime of $B$ under the identification done via $f$, hence that $P\in f^{-1}(V)$.

Is this proof correct? It is far too handwavy for my taste, but I don't know how to write a more formal proof. What would be the right way to write down a complete formal proof of this?

**Edit:** (in an attempt to make my doubt more precise)

Why is the image under $f$ of the isomorphic image of $\operatorname{Spec}{A}$ in $X$ contained in $\operatorname{Spec}{B}$? And why is the restriction of $f$ to this isomorphic image the same as the map induced by the inclusion of rigns?

I suspect this to be true because we are using $f$ to identify $B$ as a subring of $K(X)$, but I fail to see how to write down an easy formal proof of this. Moreover, since Hartshorne writes "clearly", I am afraid that the answer is actually easy and it may follow directly from some of the things I wrote above. But I don't see how.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This proof looks fine. What do you believe to be "handwavy" about it?

Comment: @KReiser "under the identification done via $f$" is the part that seems the most handwavy to me, and also the part that I don't see how to formalize. It seems to me that I would need to write all the isomorphisms involved (including $\operatorname{Spec}{A}\cong U\subseteq X$) and argue somehow that the resulting diagram commutes. Why is a prime $P$ of $B$ lying under some prime $Q$ in $A$ the image of $A_{Q}$ under $f$? Drawing a picture and taking into account that we see $B\subseteq K(X)$ via $f$, this seems very reasonable. But still I don't see how to write it down properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an attempt to assuage your concerns about "under the identification done via $f$", I present the following lemma:

Lemma: A dominant morphism $f:X\to Y$ induces an injection on coordinate algebras $f^*:\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y)\to \mathcal{O}_X{X}$.

Proof: Suppose $c\in \mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y)$ is in the kernel of $f^*$. Then $c$ must vanish on $f(X)$. But if $f$ is dominant, then $f(X)$ is dense, so $c$ must be the zero function.

How do we use this to eliminate the doubts you have? Set $\operatorname{Spec} B = V\subset Y$ an affine open subset. Then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$, and furthermore, by the lemma above, $B \hookrightarrow K[f^{-1}V]$ which embeds into $K(X)$. So we have a morphism $B\hookrightarrow K(X)$ which is an injection. This gives you $B$ as a subring of $K(X)$ in a natural way and it would be compatible with anything you would ever want.

Responding to edit made 10/03: The question has been clarified to ask why $f(\operatorname{Spec} A)\subset \operatorname{Spec} B$.

First: why does $f$ match the map induced by ring inclusions? Because the ring inclusion $A\subset B$ is performed via $f$. Tracing the definitions, the ring map $A\to K(Y)\to K(X)$ is performed by the natural embedding of a domain into it's field of fractions and then sending a rational function in $K(Y)$ to a rational function in $K(X)$ by pulling back via $f$.

So $f$ is the map on spectrums induced by the ring inclusion $i:B\to A$. Since for any morphism of affine schemes induced by a ring map we have that the image of a prime ideal on the scheme side is it's preimage on the ring side, we have that for $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec} A$, $f(\mathfrak{p})= B\cap\mathfrak{p}$, which is an ideal of $B$. Furthermore, there are no ideals of $A$ which have trivial intersection with $B$: given an element $a\in A\setminus B$, if an ideal contains $a$, then the ideal contains all powers of $a$, and the monic polynomial in $B$ which vanishes on $a$ (which exists because $A$ is an integral extension of $B$) enables us to write a $B$-linear combination of powers of $a$ as an element of $B$. This shows that $f(\operatorname{Spec} A)\subset \operatorname{Spec} B$.

Comment: In what sense is this a natural identification? The last sentence is precisely my problem. Could you elaborate on that? What kind of compatibilities are you talking about? Maybe some examples of situations in which this compatibilities apply, besides the proposition in question?

Comment: It's an injection, and in particular, it's an isomorphism on to it's image. There's no reason for you to be worrying about drawing diagrams and hoping they commute here - this is a straightforwards, down-to-earth commutative algebra question about the relationship between ideals in an extension of commutative rings. Work with elements here, not diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments. This may be entirely my fault and it may be as straightforward and down to earth as you said. But I fail to see how this answers my question. The only thing you said that I didn't write myself when posting the question was the last sentence in your answer, and I am asking precisely for a clarification on this sentence. As mentioned in my comment below the answer, I am in fact working with elements (which seems to me to be the same as checking that a certain diagram commutes anyway)

Comment: See the most recent edit.

Comment: @KReiser Hi,KReiser, I realized this question was asked two years ago and you might not still be interested in it, but I am working on this problem at the moment and I feel that there is a clearer argument, maybe I can share it here with you.

Comment: I think, to show $f(\operatorname{Spec}A) \subset \operatorname{Spec}B$, we let $p$ be a non zero prime ideal of $A$, then $A_p$ is a DVR with fraction field $K(X)$. Let $q=B\bigcap p$. Then we claim that the point in $\operatorname{Spec}A$ corresponding to $p$, we call it $x$, is mapped by $f$ to the point in $\operatorname{Spec}B$ corresponding to $q$, we call it $y$.

Comment: Indeed, consider $\operatorname{Spec}A_p$, we have $A_p$ dominates $O_{f(x),Y}$ by the definition of morphism between locally ringed spaces. Hence the map sending the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec}A_p$ to the generic point of $Y$ and the closed point of $\operatorname{Spec}A_p$ to $f(x)$ gives a morphism from $\operatorname{Spec}A_p$ to $Y$. Since $Y$ is separated, by the valuative criterion of separatedness, there exist at most one such morphism, but sending $x$ to $y$ clearly induces one such morphism, hence we must have $f(x)=y$. Does this argument makes sense to you? Thank you!